# A seasonal riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> After spring, I’m a hiker’s delight.
>
> In the summer, I help children play.
>
> Before fall, I will tumble with might.
>
> And come winter, I’ll sleep in all day.

**What am I?**

Comment: This is my first attempt at a riddle, feedback welcome! And yes, the wordplay tag is intentional. (may or may not be a hint ;-))

Comment: First riddle? Wow. I am favouriting this ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are

> Water

After spring, I’m a hiker’s delight.

> **Spring-water** would be refreshing to a hiker

In the summer, I help children play.

> Children play in water (pools / sprinklers) in the summer

Before fall, I will tumble with might.

> a **Water-fall** tumbles with might!

And come winter, I’ll sleep in all day.

> Water may become solid ice in winter

Comment: Wow, that was fast! I’ll wait a bit before giving the check, but you got it all right!

Comment: Nice puzzle!  I DID take the wordplay tag as a hint, which helped a lot.

Comment: That wasn’t a very well disguised hint, huh? Maybe next time I’ll make things harder ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I know it's already been answered, but this also works.  You are:

> A stick

After spring, I’m a hiker’s delight.

> Hikers appreciate a good walking stick.

In the summer, I help children play.

> Kids like to play with sticks.

Before fall, I will tumble with might.

> Leaves and dry sticks tend to fall from trees in the autumn.

And come winter, I’ll sleep in all day.

> Trees and fallen branches will sleep through the winter under a blanket of snow.

Comment: That works too, although it doesn’t take advantage of the wordplay tag. +1 from me anyway, good answer!